# Delete HTML Tag with VIM

Tags: vim

I want to delete a single tag, like `<strong>`.  I don't want to delete anything else, just that tag.

`dat` deletes `<strong>content</strong>`

`dit` deletes `content`.

`df>` works, but I have to have the cursor on `<`, otherwise it does not.

I want a quick set of key presses that deletes the entire tag without being quite so cursor-sensitive. Is that possible?

Comment: You don't want to use regex substitution with confirmation? That would take you to each tag

Comment: Nah, I was just deleting one tag under my cursor and realized I didn't have an easy command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vim is able to match parenteses and such. So you should be able to use `da<` or `da>` to delete a tag.

Comment: That's great, answer accepted. Can you explain why it works?

Comment: @JoshuaD Check `:help a<`; it's a text object provided by vim.

Answer (score 1):

`dawdaw` could do, but it's probably too long. You could bind it...

```
:map <F12> dawdaw
```

Also, it works only if you're inside the tag name.